# Java: What does "a method trails another method" really means?

Tags: java

I have met the text "`doSomethind()` method is modiffied to trail another method", and it is not very clear to me what does this means?

- Does it means that it is calling the "another method"?
- Does it means it is overwriting or overridding the "another method"?
- Does it means that it is called by the "another method"?

I am really confused.

Comment: Can you post the relevant code?

Comment: It would be better to post some more surrounding text. It's not very clear, as it's not a standard term.

Comment: Can you copy-paste the actual text? What you've posted has multiple typos; either you didn't reproduce it correctly, in which case the actual text may be more intelligible, or the actual text is riddled with typos, in which case you may be best off ignoring it and reading the code.

Comment: It's not very clear to be either, but I have only been programming for 28 years.  Perhaps they are talking about http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining

Comment: @PeterLawrey Lol, only 28?

Comment: I cannot post the code, because there is none. It is just a question: "If doSomethings(), that has no exception handling code, trails a method that throws an exception, what will make the code to compile?"

Comment: @PeterLawrey "but I have only been programming for 28 years" +1 That made me laugh.

Comment: I guess `trails` should have been `calls` or `invokes`, to make it more clear. Where is that text? A book?

Comment: @PeterLawrey - Your programming experience exceeds my age by a fair amount... lol.. :P

Comment: @Rohit Jain: It is a question met in the simulations of the OCA exam. Qnd the explaining is not linked to the "trail" word

Comment: @TheLostMind When I had by first PC, 16 MB of memory cost more than ten houses.

Comment: @PeterLawrey - I believe houses were cheap at that time.. :P

Comment: @TheLostMind Much cheaper, < 100K for a three bedroom.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I wrote my first BASIC program in '83 so I beat you by two years. In fact, I should be celebrating my 30-year jubilee :)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I could be similar. I used to write code on a TRS-80 at the local shopping centre in BASIC.  However, I didn't get into it seriously until '85 when my parents bought me an NEC APC which ran at a true 5 MHz instead of 4.77 ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey I got into it *seriously* much, much later :)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik By *seriously* I mean every day of the week. ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey Yeah, that's far above my early commitment to programming... I was on and off it, did serious work only when I got an interesting idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Method trailing" is not a defined term in Computer Science or Java. It appears that the person who wrote this text is using their own private terminology. You should ask them to find out.

My personal speculation would conclude in that:

- The author means that the method is placed before another method in the source code; or
- The author is refering to [Method chaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining)

Answer (score 1):

> "If doSomethings(), that has no exception handling code, trails a method that throws an exception, what will make the code to compile?"

"Trails" could mean anything.  I would have assumed it just means it appears after another method in the class file, but I assume the author had something else in mind.

"no exception handling code"  This doesn't imply anything at all.  In the code below, there is no exception handling code and it compiles fine.

There is nothing in the quote which suggests you need to do anything special to write a method which compiles.

Warning:  some web sites (rose india comes to mind) have lots of written material which is technically confused and shouldn't be read too closely, if at all.  They are like a lot of marketing, nice on the surface, but the more you think about them, the less sense they make ;)

---

Say you have code like this

```
public void a() {
    b();
}

public void b() {
    c();
}
```

> Does it means that it is calling the "another method"?

Method `b` is calling another method named `c`

> Does it means it is overwriting or overridding the "another method"?

Overriding means it overrides a method defining in a parent class instead of inheriting it.

Overwriting is something you can do to a file, but not a method.

> Does it means that it is called by the "another method"?

Method `b` is called by another method named`a`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a case of Method Chaining:

public class SomeClass {

```
public SomeClass method1() {
    // code here
    return this;
}

public SomeClass method2() {
    // code here
    return this;
}
```

}

**Usage:**

```
SomeClass someObj = new SomeClass();
someObj.method1().method2();
```

This pattern is a somewhat niche one but it appears in many places (like Query frameworks) or used together with other patterns (like the Builder pattern).

There is no **overriding/overloading** in either case and they are not calling each other either.

Comment: To the contrary, Fluent APIs are very *in* these days. (nothing to do with your downvote)

Comment: Damn. I wanted that "only upvote" hat.

Comment: Wait, there are hats around again? Haven't noticed that...

Comment: What is the "only upvote" hat?

Comment: Yea. I only noticed them today :)

Comment: You get a hat if you receive only upvotes for a day: [Winterbash 2013](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/)